# push_back on 2D std::vector< std::vector<char*> > value made all the values are the same

Tags: c++, sqlite, char, stdvector

How can I adding the value in 2D vector std::vector< std::vector<char*> >

I was using this code, but the items result inside the vetore are the same. Whereas the data from the db querying are varied.

```
std::vector< std::vector<char*> >  results;
char *dataTemp = new char[128];
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(m_pDbFile, sql, -1, &statement, 0);
if( rc == SQLITE_OK )
{
    int cols = sqlite3_column_count(statement);
    int result = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        result = sqlite3_step(statement);
        if(result == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            std::vector<char*, std::allocator<char*>> values;
            for(int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
            {
                char* value = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, col);
                values.push_back((char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, col));
            }
            results.push_back(values);
        }
        else
        {
            break;  
        }
        count++;
    }
    
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

Comment: You're saving `char*`. There is no guarantee in SQLite the buffer it refers to won't be reused on the next fetch. If you want to save that data *you* need to make a copy prior (use `std::string`, btw, which as Mohit pointed out, will make your code as-is simply "work"). From the SQLite documentation: `"The pointers returned are valid until a type conversion occurs as described above, or until sqlite3_step() or sqlite3_reset() or sqlite3_finalize() is called."`

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**
Pointer (C type string) returned by `sqlite3_column_text` may be invalidated / reused after subsequent calls to sql APIs. So you should preserve the contents instead of saving the pointer itself.

**Solution**
Make the following 3 changes in your code.

```
#include <string>  // 1
...
std::vector< std::vector<std::string> >  results;  // 2
...
            std::vector<std::string> values;  // 3
            for(int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
            {
                const char* value = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, col);  // Optional
                values.push_back(value);  // Optional
            }
...
```

Comment: Hi, thak you for the answer, however this have not solved the problem. The result is still make the same items. The vector  values inside main vector (results variable) contain the same value. The latest vector<char*> added to the main vector will change all off previous vector<char*>'s

Comment: Although I made like this 
std::vector< const std::vector<const char*> >  results;  
...
  std::vector<const char*> values;
                for(int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
                {
     const char* value = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, col);
     values.push_back(value);
                }
    const std::vector<const char*> valuesAdded(values);
    results.push_back(valuesAdded);

Comment: How do you know they are same? Did you use debugger or printed the values. I would suggest print the value when you insert it in vector and after the loop ends, print the complete vector.

Comment: Yes, I'm using debugger vs2010

Comment: Can you add the prints as I suggested and change the vector to contain `std::string` instead of `char *` and share the output?